# How to add a value to session using Celery in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I've created a task that adds a value to session so then i can access it through browser , my celery is running perfectly, here are my **codes**:

```
from flask import session, g
from ..extensions import celery

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-10-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.ruble',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=20)
    }
}

@celery.task(name='tasks.ruble')
def ruble():
    url = 'https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=KGS&to=RUB&meta=ei%3DmSr0WeHCCYvBsAH8n6OIBA'
    urlHandler = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = urlHandler.read()
    bsoup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    num = bsoup.find('span').text.split()[0]
    g.get('ruble', float(num))
    session['get_ruble'] = float(num)
```

but when the times come to execute the task, it ends up with this error:

```
[2017-10-30 19:19:29,372: ERROR/PoolWorker-4] Task tasks.ruble[ff7617ad-764b-455c-b541-96f3ba78a87b] raised unexpected: RuntimeError('Working outside of request context.\n\nThis typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed\nan active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for\ninformation about how to avoid this problem.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xakep/Desktop/work/optomvse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 367, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xakep/Desktop/work/optomvse/celery_worker.py", line 21, in __call__
    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xakep/Desktop/work/optomvse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 622, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xakep/Desktop/work/optomvse/develop/tasks.py", line 34, in ruble
    session['get_ruble'] = float(num)
  File "/home/xakep/Desktop/work/optomvse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 350, in __setitem__
    self._get_current_object()[key] = value
  File "/home/xakep/Desktop/work/optomvse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/home/xakep/Desktop/work/optomvse/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 37, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Another thing i forgot to mention is that i also tried to use `g` instead of session , by just assigning the `float(num)` value to it so `g.ruble = float(num)`, but inside my template if i typed `{{g.ruble}}` nothing get printed out .

Comment: How are you calling this code? If you want to modify the request context, it's probably something that should be done syncronously, not as an async task. If you want to periodically get data from another web site, you can store that data in the database, with redis/memcached or in a file, not in the session object.

Comment: @HåkenLid, thanks for your interest mate, i want to store the value in session just because the value of the currency is changing every time so saving it in session would be more sufficient !!

Comment: If you need to access the value in your template, you can fetch it syncronously for each request. So without using celery at all.

Comment: @HåkenLid, thanks about your suggestions ;) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value keeps changing store it somewhere (Redis/ any database) and when the request from the user comes just update the session data in the API call.

```
session['get_ruble'] = get_stored_value()
```

You can not update the session data asynchronously since you don't have the request context in the async task.

*Just a suggestion:*

If the value is so dynamic instead of storing it in the session, you can provide a separate API to fetch the latest data.

Comment: i think you are right , just making a small api for getting the current value of any currency will be sufficient, also the database would be great , thanks again for your help :) .

Comment: you too for upvoting my question ;)